# Grails - sort by the domain relation attribute (using createCriteria())

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes with 1:n relationship:

```
import Action

class Task {    
    Action actionParent
    String taskName
}
```

and

```
class Action {
    String actionName
}
```

I have the list of Tasks where I have the column "Action name", I would like to sort this column by Action.actionName. Now I'm using the createCriteria() method [I need to use it because I have more logic for filtering and sorting...], but I'm able to sort only by "Action.id". This method looks like:

```
def criteria = Task.createCriteria();
taskList = criteria.list {
    if(parameters.max != null)
        maxResults(parameters.max)
    if(parameters.offset != null)
        firstResult(new Integer(parameters.offset))
    if(parameters.sort != null && parameters.order)
        order(parameters.sort, parameters.order)
}
```

Is there any way to sort the domain class data by the relationship attributes?

Thanks for any replay,

Mateo

Comment: Mark as answered.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to stick with the criteria approach, try something like this. Create an alias to you Action object and then access the property for sorting it

```
    def criteria = Task.createCriteria()
    def taskList = criteria.list {
        createAlias("actionParent","_action")
        order( "_action.actionName")
    }
```

Comment: alternative without alias:

`def taskList = criteria.list {
  actionParent {
    order("actionName")
  }
}`

Comment: Although the answer and the comment look very promising and *should* work, they did not for me. It seems to be a bug in hibernate... The Answer from @jstricker helped me to sort by the property of an association by simply adding a param.sort = "actionParent.actionName".

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but in my particular situation (wanting to sort on an association's association's field), it worked only when I passed the sort column directly into the list method:

```
def criteria = Task.createCriteria();
taskList = criteria.list(max: parameters.max, offset: parameters.offset, sort: parameters.sort, order: parameters.order) {
    // Other code here...
}
```

When I tried to put the ordering information in the closure itself, Hibernate barfed up an exception with a message `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: [Grails domain relation's relation's field] of: [Grails domain]`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the listOrderBy* GORM command, so it would be something like

```
def tasksList = Task.listOrderByActionName()
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 def tasksList = Task.findAll()
 tasksListSorted = tasksList.sort { it.actionParent.actionName }
```

you can also do this

```
 tasksList.sort{
        task1, task2 -> task1.actionParent.actionName.compareToIgnoreCase(task2.actionParent.actionName)

    }
```