# grails: sort by nested attributes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to sort by nested attributes using *where queries*?

I have 2 domain classes:

```
class Parent {
    String name
    Child child
}
```

and

```
class Child {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}
```

This works:

```
Parent.where {}.list(sort: 'name')
```

and this doesn't:

```
Parent.where {}.list(sort: 'child.name')
```

I have an error:

```
could not resolve property: child.name of: Parent
```

I am using grails 2.3.x

Answer (score 11):

See this: [Grails - sort by the domain relation attribute (using createCriteria())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383231/grails-sort-by-the-domain-relation-attribute-using-createcriteria)

Solution 1:

```
    def criteria = Child.createCriteria();
    println criteria.list{
        createAlias("parent","_parent")
        order( "_parent.name")
    }
```

Solution 2:

```
    def criteria = Child.createCriteria();
    println criteria.list{
        parent {
            order("name")
        }
    }
```

Solution 3:

```
class Child {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]

    public String getParentName(){
        return parent.getName()
    }
}

println Child.listOrderByParentName()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok, so I understand, that it is not possible to do it with where queries - I need Criteria/DetachedCriteria. That is a pity

Comment: I could not get your Solution 2 to work. Solution 3 works only in unit tests, not in application code